# PHP: Interacting with 'selected values' in a html form

Tags: php, html

I have run a successful php page that interacts with a html page. However, there is once instance towards the end where the php does not interact as it is intended to.

The problem I am having, is that the page always executes "Andrew hates you" no matter what colour is picked, or if any colour is picked at all. I only want this message to show if the user has picked ' RED ' . I want the message "Andrew likes you" to show if ' GREEN ', ' YELLOW ', ' BLUE ' or ' PURPLE ' have been selected.

THE HTML PAGE:

```
 <html>
 <head>
 <title>Test</title><br />
 </head>
 <body>
 <form action="website.php" method="POST">
 <p><strong>Name:</strong></br>
 <input type="text" name="user"/></p>
 <p><strong>Age:</strong><br/>
 <input type="text" name="age"/></p>
 <p><strong>What's your favourite colour?</strong><br/><br>
 <select name="colour[]" multiple="multiple">
 <option value="Green">Green</option>
 <option value="Blue">Blue</option>
 <option value="Red">Red</option>
 <option value="Yellow">Yellow</option>
 <option value="Purple">Purple</option>
 </select>
 <p><input type="submit" value="Submit"/></p>
 </form>


 </body>
 </html>
```

THE PHP PAGE:

```
 //the first part of this php page works perfectly

 <?php
 echo "<p>Hi <b>". $_POST["user"]."!</p>"; 
 echo "<p>You are <b>".$_POST["age"]."</b><p>";
 echo "<p> Your favourite colour is: <br/>";
 if (!empty($_POST["colour"])) {
echo "<ul>";
foreach ($_POST ["colour"] as $value) {
    echo "<li>$value</li>";
}
echo "</ul>";
 }
 ?>   

  //this is where things start to break down

 <?php

 $funny_colour = "Red";

    if ($_POST["$value"] = $funny_colour) {
$message = "Andrew hates you";    // Always shows no matter what
echo $message;
    } else if ($_POST["$value"] != $funny_colour) {
$message = "Andrew likes you";    // Never shows 
echo $message;
  }

  ?>
```

Thanks for helping out, I really appreciate it and will endeavour to answer some of your questions.

Comment: You need to use `==` for comparison (`===` to compare the value and the data type), not `=`. And `$value` might be undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will get $_POST["colour"] as array.

```
$funny_colour = "Red";

foreach ($_POST ["colour"] as $value) {
    if ($value == $funny_colour) {
          $message = "Andrew hates you";    // Always shows no matter what
          echo $message;
    } else if ($value != $funny_colour) {
          $message = "Andrew likes you";    // Never shows 
          echo $message;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($_POST["$value"] = $funny_colour)
```

is incorrect, you've to use `==` or `===` to compare. 
`=` is an assign and will always return true.

Moreover, $value is set only in the foreach loop, you already lost it when you tried to use it in your `if`.

Comment: Give a look at parixit's answer, I think that's what you need.